# eBay SDK Add Order Transaction Id

Tags: ebay-api

I am using the eBay SOAP SDK Sample. I am trying to add an order, but it asks me for a transaction Id. How do I obtain a transaction Id? I entered the number 1 and it says it cannot find it. I just signed up today and my store is empty.

```
        private void BtnAddOrder_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            TxtOrderId.Text = "";

            AddOrderCall apicall = new AddOrderCall(Context);


            OrderType order = new OrderType();
            order.TransactionArray = new TransactionTypeCollection();
            order.ShippingDetails = new ShippingDetailsType();
            order.PaymentMethods = new BuyerPaymentMethodCodeTypeCollection();

            TransactionType tr1 = new TransactionType();
            tr1.Item = new ItemType();
            tr1.Item.ItemID = TxtItemIdOne.Text;
            tr1.TransactionID = TxtTransactionIdOne.Text;
            order.TransactionArray.Add(tr1);

            TransactionType tr2 = new TransactionType();
            tr2.Item = new ItemType();
            tr2.Item.ItemID = TxtItemIdTwo.Text;
            tr2.TransactionID = TxtTransactionIdTwo.Text;
            order.TransactionArray.Add(tr2);

            order.ShippingDetails.PaymentInstructions = TxtPaymentInstructions.Text;
            ShippingServiceOptionsType shpopt = new ShippingServiceOptionsType();
            shpopt.ShippingService = CboShipSvc.SelectedItem.ToString();
            shpopt.ShippingServicePriority = 1;

            order.ShippingDetails.ShippingServiceOptions = new ShippingServiceOptionsTypeCollection();
            shpopt.ShippingServiceCost = new AmountType();
            shpopt.ShippingServiceCost.currencyID = CurrencyUtility.GetDefaultCurrencyCodeType(Context.Site);

            if (TxtShipCost.Text.Length > 0) 
            {
                shpopt.ShippingServiceCost.Value = Convert.ToDouble(TxtShipCost.Text);
            }
            order.ShippingDetails.ShippingServiceOptions.Add(shpopt);

            order.Total = new AmountType();
            order.Total.currencyID = CurrencyUtility.GetDefaultCurrencyCodeType(Context.Site);
            if (TxtTotal.Text.Length > 0)
                order.Total.Value = Convert.ToDouble(TxtTotal.Text);
            order.CreatingUserRole = (TradingRoleCodeType) Enum.Parse(typeof(TradingRoleCodeType), CboRole.SelectedItem.ToString());

            order.PaymentMethods.AddRange(new BuyerPaymentMethodCodeType[] {BuyerPaymentMethodCodeType.PaymentSeeDescription});

            string orderid = apicall.AddOrder(order);


            TxtOrderId.Text = orderid;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This call is used to join two Orders so the Buyer can pay together.
See this [AddOrder Reference](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/AddOrder.html).
It is asking you for the Transaction Id's from your store to join into one order. If it can not find the Transaction Id then you have likely entered an non-existent one. In your case that is almost definitely the case. ( Transaction Ids are 9 digit strings if I remember correctly).

What I think your looking for is this, [PlaceOffer Reference](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/PlaceOffer.html).
Your going to need to have some items though.

Good Luck with Ebay API.